# Custom Input Form Angular

Tags: angular

I have to modify an input field like this :

```
<input
type="text"
formControlName="name"
placeholder="placeholder"
(keypress)="function"
(focus)="function"
```

to put this code in a template and create a component to do the same thing like this code but by using a component as well as I can create a text input field by writing

```
<templateSelector formControlName="..." placeholder="..." (keypress)="..."
```

I doesn't know how to create a component for input text and how get input value in my form like when I use

Could you help me please ?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a Directive. Directives are like Components, except they don't have a template. Instead you place them on a host element. Follow the docs here:

https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives